# How to set the default dimension of an application window

Tags: linux, unix

Every time I open nedit/gedit applications on my machine, the application loads in a small window. I have to resize the window each and every time. Is there any way to set a higher default dimension for these application windows?
And FYI: I use Oracle Enterprise Linux in XTERM mode

Comment: Thanks Marius. Your solution works perfect. But isn't there a unix inbuilt solution for controlling the default dimensions of an application? Without using any third-party apps like wmctrl???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use wmctrl to do that. You may have to install it from the repos. After installing it, open a gedit window, position it and re-size it as you like. Now go to a terminal and issue the command:

```
wmctrl -lG
```

You will get an output containing many lines like this one:

```
0x02400012  2 912  23   794  176  rasal Untitled [modified] – gedit
```

Columns 3-6 are offsets of the window corners. Your values will be different from mine. Now, if you issue these commands,

```
gedit myfile.txt &
wmctrl -r gedit -e -e 0,0,0,640,480
```

(insert your values here instead of mine, 0,0,0,640,480) you will have a window positioned and sized as you like it.

If you wish to make this automatic, make a file called mygedit (or whatever you wish to call it) in your bin directory, make sure you bin is in your search path, chmod 755 the file, insert into it this text:

```
#!/bin/sh
gedit $1 &
wmctrl -r gedit -e -e 0,0,0,640,480
```

and from now on you may invoke gedit, correctly sized and positioned, with the command

```
mygedit myfile.txt
```